# Flutter web canvaskit renderer not showing Network images

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, flutter-image, flutter2.0, canvaskit

I have A list of `Images.network("$imgUrl")` in my flutter app

It works fine on phones (Android and IOS even on phone Browsers) but it does not work on desktop browser.
however images are shown when i use `flutter build web --web-renderer html`
should'n it work on `canvaskit renderer` (which is the default renderer in my case) too?

i'm using Flutter 2.0.1 stable channel

Comment: Anyone has any update on this stupid bug? 
For which I spent countless hours fixing my own image in assets/server etc etc 

Answer (score 1):

I need to use canvaskit. I am finding some way can fix it too.

Now, I found 2 methods.

1.

```
Image.network('https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/' + imageUrl)
```

2. 

```
import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:ui' as UI;

String imageUrl = ".png";
  
  @override
  void initState() {
    ui.platformViewRegistry.registerViewFactory(
      imageUrl,
          (int viewId) => ImageElement()..src = imageUrl,
    );
    super.initState();
  }

  Widget showImg() {
    return SizedBox(
            width: 250,
            height: 250,
            child: HtmlElementView(viewType: imageUrl),
          );
  }
```

And add this below in analysis_option.yaml

```
analyzer:
  errors:
    undefined_prefixed_name: ignore
```

I think, There has some method about setting in flutter but I don't understand and have not seen any video about this.

If someone knows about this, please give the answer

Answer (score 0):

If you're still looking for a workaround, changing CanvasKit to Html while running or building the project is a potential solution

```
flutter run -d chrome --web-renderer html
flutter build web --web-renderer canvaskit
```

Please have a read ->

https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/web-renderers

Comment: yeah this is technically a workaround but my animations heavy app for which I am using the canvas kit for doesn't really work as a workaround, but for devs okay with html renderer should work.